# Fully disable main monitor on a tablet/notebook

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I'm using an HDMI monitor with my Windows 10 tablet, with the `Show only on 2` option.

While it works fine, I can see that the display on the tablet itself is still on with a but with no image - really annoying in the dark and wasting battery/screen life for no good reason.

How can I turn it off?

BTW:

- The touchscreen is also on.
- The intel HD drivers are installed correctly

Answer (score 0):

It could try creating a [Power Plan](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2843-power-plan-settings-change-windows-10-a.html) that turns the screen off after a short period of time.  You might not be able to decouple this setting from putting the tablet to sleep, though.

Answer (score 0):

From a software perspective the screen is off, its just the backlight that's on because the system is powered on. Presumably there is no sleep function as what you're doing isn't really the intended use.

That would mean the options are:

- Turn the brightness all the way down  then change to the other
  display, it may be then less noticable
- Open the casing and unplug the backlight cable
- Put something on top to hide it

Comment: Yeah, maximum dimming of the backlight might be the only workable solution.